# How to make a array of strings

Tags: ios, arrays, string

Two Questions:

**First question:**

I want to make arrays of strings like this:

Country[1]=Norway;
Capital[1]=Oslo;

Country[2]=Germany;
Capital[2]=Berlin;

How do I write this code? It should be simple, but I don't understand any of the explanations that I've seen. I guess I want to use a NSArray, because I don't want to change them!
I guess the main question is how I declare this array!

**Second question:**

Can I use for example Capital[2] in a button text? It is like a quiz and I want this to be one of the options if Country[2] is the given country.

/a noob

Comment: [Read the docs. They explain everything](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i).

Comment: Remember indicies are 0 based, so it'd be 0, 1; not 1, 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way to declare an `NSArray` in Obj-c is like this:

```
NSArray *Countries = @[@"Norway", @"Germany"];
NSArray *Capitals = @[@"Oslo", @"Berlin"];
```

You can then access those indexes later using `[]` notation:

```
[myButton setTitle:Capitals[1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**REMEMBER** Arrays in programming languages are 0-indexed!  That means the first element is index 0, second is index 1 and so forth

Comment: This code will not compile.  You should call the `[UIButton setTitle:forState:]` method instead.  UIButton does not have a property called `title`.

Comment: I always forget that, and is always a pain in the butt when I try to programmatically change my buttons

Answer (score 1):

**First Answer**

Given your example, you can achieve it with Array literals:

```
NSArray* countries = @[@"Norway", @"Germany"];
NSArray* capitals = @[@"Oslo", @"Berlin"];
```

But, the capital cities are decoupled from the countries, there is a possibility that they could be out of sync. A better representation would be an array dictionaries:

```
NSArray* countries = @[@{@"name":@"Norway", @"capital":@"Oslo"},
                       @{@"name":@"Germany", @"capital":@"Berlin"}];
```

**Second Answer**

Of course you can! Assuming you have a UIButton on screen, accessible via the property `button`. With the original arrays, for Germany, you'd use:

```
[self.button setTitle:capitals[1] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

For the dictionary, you'd use:

```
NSDictionary* selectedCountry = countries[1];
NSString* country = selectedCountry[@"name"];
NSString* capital = selectedCountry[@"capital"];
[self.button setTitle:capital forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *country = @[@"Norway", @"Germany"];
NSArray *capital = @[@"Oslo", @"Berlin"];
NSString *capitalOfGermany = capital[1];

berlinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[berlinButton setTitle:capitalOfGermany forState:UIControlStateNormal];
berlinButton.frame = CGRectMake(120, 200, 80, 20);

[self addSubview:berlinButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not an array of strings you want, it's an array of dictionaries:

```
NSArray *countryArray = @[ @{@"Country" : @"Norway", @"Capital" : @"Oslo"},
                        @{@"Country" : @"Germany", @"Capital" : @"Berlin"} ];
```

**Edit** I corrected the variable declaration.

Comment: Okay, that seems to be a better way! But when I just copy your code I get the error "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" and the warning "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSDictionary *_strong' with an expression of type 'NSArray *'. 
What am I doing wrong? :P

Comment: How do I get the value later? Like dict.Country[0] and dict.Capital[0] or what? :)

Comment: Can I make a third String in the Dictionary, containing a flag file.. for example @"Flagfile" : @"Germany.png" and later put it in a image view? :)

Comment: @user1344659 Yes you can - although no you are in real world territory and putting things in a dictionary is possible, but you want to look at something like CoreData.

Comment: Okay, do you know the answer for my first two questions? :P Would really appreciate it! :)